# Inconveniencia con columnas de bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo un footer hecho a partir de la barra de navegación de bootstrap, la cosa es que estoy intentando ubicar ciertas columnas dentro de filas que también son columnas de una fila principal.

He aquí el [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWdRaa)

Verán un div naranjo y otro celeste. Si achican la pantalla hasta llegar a 767px, el div celeste se sale del costado y se sobrepone al div naranjo.

No tengo idea de por qué ocurre, pero lo curioso es que 767px es el mismo ancho de pantalla al que el togglebutton (El botón de tres barritas que minimiza una barra de navegación) hace su efecto.

Entonces necesito que el div naranjo no pierda su posición cuando el ancho de pantalla sea menor a 767px.

¿Por qué ocurre esto? ¿Cómo lo arreglo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu bloque tool1, tiene una clase col-xs-2 esta es activa en tamaños menos a 768, dado que solo le pusiste el valor de 2 (col-xs-2) ... llega a ser muy pequeña y el de su costado la oculta

```
<div id="tool1" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">hey</div>
```

Puedes probar algo como lo siguiente

```
<div id="tool1" class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">hey</div>
```

Comment: Vaya no lo había visto! creo que me estoy quedando dormido. Graicias :D